# What does BR2_JLEVEL=2 do in Buildroot?

Tags: buildroot

I have set the BR2_JLEVEL to 2 ; Not sure how this option works in buildroot ? can somebody give details on how it works in buildroot as I am not seeing improvements in my build timing.

Comment: can you please tell me where did you set it? in the *.mk file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BR2_JLEVEL is equivalent to running 'Make' with the option -j.

The man-page for 'make' states

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
>
> Specifies  the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.
>     If there is more than one -j option, the last one is
>     effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will
>     not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

So running with BR2_JLEVEL=2 will start two compile processes at the same time, and thus speedup compile time, especially if you have more than one CPU.